# ORACLE SQL AND/OR combination

Tags: sql, oracle, select

i need some help with an `SELECT` statement that i wrote.

The statement looks like:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT MANDT, PATH301 
FROM    NC301B
WHERE   EDIPROC like 'P30_'
    AND (LF301M > 0) 
    AND (MANDT LIKE '011')
    AND (PATH301 NOT LIKE '%:\saptemp%')
    AND (PATH301 NOT LIKE '%:\SAPTEMP%')  
    AND (PATH301 NOT LIKE '%usr%')  
    AND (PATH301 NOT LIKE '%:\Windows%')
    AND (PATH301 NOT LIKE '%PKV_DAV%')
    AND (PATH301 NOT LIKE '%pkv_dav%');
```

Now i need to check for an additional `MANDT` -> `MANDT LIKE '012'`

My problem is that the output is not correct when i add the line `OR (MANDT LIKE '012')` to the statement.

My idea was:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT MANDT, PATH301 
FROM    NC301B
WHERE   EDIPROC like 'P30_'
    AND (LF301M > 0) 
    AND (MANDT LIKE '011')
    OR (MANDT LIKE '012')
    AND (PATH301 NOT LIKE '%:\saptemp%')
    AND (PATH301 NOT LIKE '%:\SAPTEMP%')  
    AND (PATH301 NOT LIKE '%usr%')  
    AND (PATH301 NOT LIKE '%:\Windows%')
    AND (PATH301 NOT LIKE '%PKV_DAV%')
    AND (PATH301 NOT LIKE '%pkv_dav%');
```

Is it possible to check for two or more `MANDT` Values in one statement
like i did in my example?

Thank you!

Comment: `...AND MANDT IN ('011', '012')...`.

Comment: why you use like in there? `MANDT= '011'` cant you use this?

Comment: we use like when we use wildcard operation like `% , _ , [ , ]`

Comment: sorry you are right. im using = instead of LIKE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pay attention to the parenthesis, try this one

```
SELECT  DISTINCT MANDT, PATH301  FROM    NC301B WHERE   EDIPROC like
'P30_'
    AND (LF301M > 0) 
     AND (MANDT LIKE '011' OR MANDT LIKE '012')
     AND (PATH301 NOT LIKE '%:\saptemp%')
     AND (PATH301 NOT LIKE '%:\SAPTEMP%')  
     AND (PATH301 NOT LIKE '%usr%')  
     AND (PATH301 NOT LIKE '%:\Windows%')
     AND (PATH301 NOT LIKE '%PKV_DAV%')
     AND (PATH301 NOT LIKE '%pkv_dav%');
```

Answer (score 2):

Put parentheses around the two checks on `MANDT`:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT MANDT, PATH301 
FROM    NC301B
WHERE   EDIPROC LIKE 'P30_' AND
    (LF301M > 0) AND
    ((MANDT LIKE '011') OR (MANDT LIKE '012')) AND
    (PATH301 NOT LIKE '%:\saptemp%') AND
    (PATH301 NOT LIKE '%:\SAPTEMP%') AND
    (PATH301 NOT LIKE '%usr%') AND
    (PATH301 NOT LIKE '%:\Windows%') AND
    (PATH301 NOT LIKE '%PKV_DAV%') AND
    (PATH301 NOT LIKE '%pkv_dav%');
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use parentheses to group the two predicates as `and` has higher precedence than `or`:

```
...
AND ( (MANDT LIKE '011') OR (MANDT LIKE '012') ) 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [REGEXP_LIKE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm) and because you do not have % in '011' and '012', you can use [IN Condition](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/conditions013.htm#SQLRF52169) :

```
SELECT DISTINCT MANDT, PATH301
  FROM NC301B
 WHERE EDIPROC LIKE 'P30_' 
   AND LF301M > 0
   AND MANDT IN ('011','012')
   AND NOT regexp_like(path301, '(:\\saptemp|:\\SAPTEMP|usr|:\\Windows|PKV_DAV|pkv_dav)')
```

Because:

> The default case sensitivity is determined by the value of the NLS_SORT parameter.

you can use the third parameter in regexp_like:

> 'i' specifies case-insensitive matching.
>
> 'c' specifies case-sensitive matching.